# Resize textarea with screen orientation in firefox os

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox-os

I'm trying to create a simple text editor for Firefox OS where I use `testarea` as user's text field. As I'm using the simulator when I change the screen orientation from portrait to landscape or vice verse I need the `textarea` to change its orientation automatically and get the full screen size. But every time I change the orientation I need to reload the app :(

and if I try `screen.orientation` it results undefined.

Bellow code I use to get the screen size

HTML:

```
<textarea id="input-text" onfocus="TextareaOnFocus()" onblur="TextareaRealeseFocus()"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
var textAreaSize = document.getElementById("input-text");
textAreaSize.style.height = screen.height - 74 + "px"; // -74, so that the field is not edge to edge 
textAreaSize.style.width = screen.width - 21 + "px"; // -21, so that the field is not edge to edge
```

And is there any way to change the keyboard size, cause it cover half of the screen so my text filed becomes very small.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the size of the textarea in CSS, as we now have cool stuff like [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and [vw/vh](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units).

```
#input-text {
   height: calc(100vh - 74px);
   width: calc(100vw - 21px);
}
```

Will automatically work when rotating as well.

---

The reason that `screen.orientation` doesn't work, is because the orientation API is non-standard at the moment, so you need to prefix with `moz`. F.e.: `screen.mozOrientation` works fine.

Comment: I fixed the width problem by width: 100% which works fine while the orientation got change. But in css if I do height: calc(100vh - 74px); or height: calc(100vh); in page load the textarea does not cover the full screen (looks like the default height of a textarea). But after that If I click on the textarea it gets the set size (full screen).